# How to add space after comma if it has letters on each side in a string using RegEx(Java)

Tags: java, regex

Example
String = "abcd,anhdc,bajb,abchb,njacsn,10,000,nijaxiu"

Result = "abcd, anhdc, bajb, abchb, njacsn, **10,000**, nijaxiu"

Space should not be there after **10,** as it is Integer

Comment: Based on which programming language you choose (let's say `C`, or `C++`, or may be assembly-language), the steps may vary. Basically, iterate through the string (by each character) & "remember" the previous iteration's character. If current iteration is a comma and previous is not a digit (ie, not 0, 1, 2, ...9), then add the comma and a space into a result string. If not, just add the character as-is to the result string.

Comment: What do you mean by "using Regression? Do you maybe mean _recursion?_

Comment: @Chris Sorry by mistake I mentioned Regression, using regex I need to do this

Comment: @jsN00b Condition will be like if before comma and after comma if it's an Integer then do not put space after comma but I don't know how to write it using Regex

Comment: @jsN00b the issue with what you're suggesting is that he could have strings that start/end with an int character. He didn't provide enough information about the problem but I am assuming that he has blocks which contain either numbers where commas are used to separate thousands or random strings with each block separated by a comma.

Comment: @PranavNigam - please update the question. You should be able to click "Edit" and change the question so it states "RegEx" and not "Regression" (particularly in the "Title"). And, you have also not mentioned which programming language you intend to use (RegEx is applicable on multiple languages).

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention which environment you are attempting to solve this problem in. So the following answer is written with the assumption that you are working with Python.

Example string:

```
abcd,anhdc,bajb,abc1hb,nj2acsn,10,000,nijaxiu
```

This code in Python should get the job done:

```
import re

s  = "abcd,anhdc,bajb,abc1hb,nj2acsn,10,000,nijaxiu"

blocks = re.findall('[a-zA-Z0-9]+', s)
seperated_blocks = ''
seperated_blocks += blocks[0] + ','

for idx in range(1, len(blocks), 1):
  if re.match('\d+', blocks[idx-1]) and re.match('\d+', blocks[idx]):
    seperated_blocks += blocks[idx]+','
  else:
    seperated_blocks += ' ' + blocks[idx]+','

seperated_blocks = seperated_blocks[0:-1]
```

Output:

```
'abcd, anhdc, bajb, abc1hb, nj2acsn, 10,000, nijaxiu'
```